# XQuery (XPath) to count the child elements and group based on number's

Tags: xpath, xquery, flwor

The sample XML files inputting and the expected output is at the bottom, need help to group based on the count of child elememts.

```
  <DashboardXML>
        <Column>
            <ColumnOrder>1</ColumnOrder>
            <ColLabel><![CDATA[test1]]></ColLabel>                
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <ColumnOrder>2</ColumnOrder>
            <ColLabel><![CDATA[t1est]]></ColLabel>       
        </Column>
          <Column>
            <ColumnOrder>3</ColumnOrder>
            <ColLabel><![CDATA[terst]]></ColLabel>       
        </Column>
    </DashboardXML>
    <DashboardXML>
        <Column>
            <ColumnOrder>1</ColumnOrder>
            <ColLabel><![CDATA[test1]]></ColLabel>                
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <ColumnOrder>2</ColumnOrder>
            <ColLabel><![CDATA[t1est]]></ColLabel>       
        </Column>
          <Column>
            <ColumnOrder>3</ColumnOrder>
            <ColLabel><![CDATA[terst]]></ColLabel>       
        </Column>
    </DashboardXML>
    <DashboardXML>
        <Column>
            <ColumnOrder>1</ColumnOrder>
            <ColLabel><![CDATA[test1]]></ColLabel>                
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <ColumnOrder>2</ColumnOrder>
            <ColLabel><![CDATA[t1est]]></ColLabel>       
        </Column>
    </DashboardXML>
    <DashboardXML>
        <Column>
            <ColumnOrder>1</ColumnOrder>
            <ColLabel><![CDATA[test1]]></ColLabel>                
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <ColumnOrder>2</ColumnOrder>
            <ColLabel><![CDATA[t1est]]></ColLabel>       
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <ColumnOrder>1</ColumnOrder>
            <ColLabel><![CDATA[test1]]></ColLabel>                
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <ColumnOrder>2</ColumnOrder>
            <ColLabel><![CDATA[t1est]]></ColLabel>       
        </Column>
    </DashboardXML>
    <DashboardXML>
        <Column>
            <ColumnOrder>1</ColumnOrder>
            <ColLabel><![CDATA[test1]]></ColLabel>                
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <ColumnOrder>2</ColumnOrder>
            <ColLabel><![CDATA[t1est]]></ColLabel>       
        </Column>
    </DashboardXML>
```

Above is the sample XML's as input and below is the XQuery:

```
for $b in /DashboardXML where count($b/Column) > 0 order by count($b/Column) return <li>{count($b/Column)} </li>
```

The query yields the below output (sample):

```
    <li>3</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>2</li>
```

Now the question is how to group the output like Below:

```
2 = 2 (counts)
3 = 2 (counts)
4 = 1 (counts)
```

Comment: Please post code and input as an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), so we can reproduce it. Your XML is not valid (missing root element) and does not fit the expected output. Either post the original document somewhere or match the expected output to the provided input. You also should tell use which version and implementation of XQuery you're using, as XQuery 3.0 knows a `group by` clause XQuery 1 does not know.

Comment: I have update as you suggested - Thanks

Comment: Question looks great now. Do you have an XQuery 3.0 compatible query processor, so I solved your question? Then you might mark it as answered (the checkmark on the left of the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you're using an XQuery 3.0 capable query processor, use the `group by` clause.

```
for $b in $xml/DashboardXML
let $count := count($b/Column)
where $count > 0
order by $count descending
group by $count
return <li>{$b/DashboardName/text()} = {$count} ({count ($b) }) </li>
```

Which will output

```
<li> = 1 (1) </li>
<li> = 2 (2) </li>
```

for the input given (notice the missing `DashboardName` elements and that I changed the `where` clause to allow any non-zero number of `Column` children).